# How do I customize the inbound email handler in Alfresco 5?

Tags: alfresco

The default Inbound `SMTP` in Alfresco creates multiple documents for e-mail content, HTML e-mail content, and also attachments.

My goal is to emulate the SharePoint behavior of creating a new folder then storing the e-mail text/contents as well as attachments in that folder.

I ran across [here](http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2012/11/alfresco-4-customize-inbound-email.html) which talks about how to modify InboundSMTP, but in Alfresco version 4.  It appears that `InboundSMTP` has changed considerably in Alfresco 5 though.  Not only does the referenced directory structure not exist, but I didn't find any InboundSMTP files anywhere in the version 5 directory structure.

**How do I go about implementing changes to InboundSMTP in Alfresco 5?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extremely short version is:

Drop XML override file (I'm using the Alfresco Git repository version as my reference/template) into `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/email/InboundSMTP/inbound` and the actual JAR with code (also using the the official repo version as a guide) into `tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib`